# Obstacle freezes during player input - Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My Python turtle game obstacle freezes when the player receives input and continues afterward:

```
# Written in Python 3
# By 
# February 4th, 2019
# Purpose: Mimic the no-wifi Google Chrome dinosaur game
# Bonus 6
import turtle # Used for graphics
from turtle import Screen # Used for inputs
import random# Used to generate a random number
import time

# Creates a turtle with the proper size and color
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape("square")
player.color("#cc0000")
player.turtlesize(1.5, 1.5)
player.penup()
player.goto(-50, 0)

# Creates the ground
ground = turtle.Turtle()
ground.shape("square")
ground.turtlesize(0.25, 300)
ground.penup()
ground.goto(0, -18)

# This function makes the square jump, unbinds 'Up', return to the ground, then rebinds 'Up'
def jump():
    Screen().onkey(null, 'Up')
    player.speed(2)
    if player.ycor() == 0:
        player.goto((player.xcor()), (player.ycor()+100))
    print("G")
    player.speed(1.5)
    player.goto(-50, 0)
    Screen().onkey(jump, 'Up')

# Blank function
def null():
    n =1

Screen().onkey(jump, 'Up')
Screen().listen()

# Ignore this
x = 3 * random.sample(range(4), 4)
print (x)
print (x[1])

# Creating obstacles (not finished, just moves)
obst1 = turtle.Turtle()
obst1.shape("square")
obst1.turtlesize(3, 2)
obst1.penup()
obst1.goto(300,0)
obst1.speed(1)
obst1.setx(-300)
```

I want the obstacle to continue moving while I jump. I only have Python 3 and its standard modules. I cannot download PIP or anything else like it, for some reason. I'm trying to mimic the dinosaur game from Google Chrome. I'm new to this sort of thing so please explain any suggestions in as much detail as possible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote your code, you can only move one turtle at a time.  Below is a rework of your code where the user controls the player, but the obstacle is controlled by a timer so they can move at the same time:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# This function unbinds 'Up', makes the square jump, return to the ground, then rebinds 'Up'
def jump():
    screen.onkey(None, 'Up')

    if player.ycor() == 0:
        player.forward(150)
        player.backward(150)

    screen.onkey(jump, 'Up')

def move():
    obstacle.forward(6)
    if obstacle.xcor() > -400:
        screen.ontimer(move, 100)

# Creates the ground
ground = Turtle('square')
ground.turtlesize(0.25, 45)
ground.penup()
ground.sety(-15)

# Creates a turtle with the proper size and color
player = Turtle('square')
player.color('red')
player.turtlesize(1.5)
player.speed('slowest')
player.penup()
player.setx(-100)
player.setheading(90)

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(jump, 'Up')
screen.listen()

# Creating obstacles (not finished, just moves)
obstacle = Turtle('square')
obstacle.turtlesize(3, 1.5)
obstacle.speed('fastest')
obstacle.penup()
obstacle.setposition(400, 15)
obstacle.setheading(180)

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

This should more closely simulate the type of motion you're trying to achieve.